# Michelson P2P message encoding

Tags: michelson, protocol

I'm looking to implement full message "forging" with no reliance on RPC calls. The [P2P message doc](http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/api/p2p.html) does not cover all the details.

Let's say I have the JSON representation of parameters and code, how do I get that into proper hex? From that document, I'm looking to understand how to construct `$scripted.contracts` and `$fitness.elem` message parts.

Comment: eztz.js library already does this - you need to convert raw code and parameters into Micheline (http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/whitedoc/michelson.html#xi-json-syntax) and then encode Micheline into hex (eztz does it here https://github.com/TezTech/eztz/blob/master/src/main.js#L824)

Comment: @StephenAndrews hi stephen! Do you mind converting your comment into an answer ? I believe it addresses the question adequtely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eztz.js library already does this - you need to convert raw code and parameters into [Micheline](https://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/whitedoc/michelson.html#xi-json-syntax) and then encode Micheline into hex (eztz does it here https://github.com/TezTech/eztz/blob/master/src/main.js#L824)